# Decorator that works on both classmethods and instance methods

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, class-method, instance-methods

I have two decorators, defined as follows, both of which do the exact same thing:

```
# ONLY WORKS FOR CLASSMETHODS
def paginated_class_method(default_page_size=25):
    def wrap(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(cls, page=1, page_size=default_page_size, *args, **kwargs):
            objects = func(cls=cls, *args, **kwargs)
            return _paginate(objects, page, page_size)
        return inner
    return wrap


# ONLY WORKS FOR INSTANCEMETHODS
def paginated_instance_method(default_page_size=25):
    def wrap(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(self, page=1, page_size=default_page_size, *args, **kwargs):
            objects = func(self=self, *args, **kwargs)
            return _paginate(objects, page, page_size)
        return inner
    return wrap
```

The reason I have two is because for class methods I need to pass in the first arg as cls=cls, and for instance methods I need to pass in self=self.  But this is obviously not ideal.  Does anyone know a way to structure a decorator that would work for instance methods and class methods?

Comment: You don't need to pass in `self` *or* `cls` as keyword arguments at all. If these were positionals instead, you could use any local name.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, I see the problem; note that the first argument to `func` is a keyword argument, either `self` or `cls`.  The real thing that needs adjustment here is not using a keyword argument for the first argument to func.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in `cls` or `self` as the first positional argument, there is *no need* to pass them is as keyword arguments:

```
def paginated_class_method(default_page_size=25):
    def wrap(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(self_or_cls, page=1, page_size=default_page_size, *args, **kwargs):
            objects = func(self_or_cls, *args, **kwargs)
            return _paginate(objects, page, page_size)
        return inner
    return wrap
```

Comment: This was the part I was missing when I tried this strategy, I think:  args = [self_or_cls] + args

Comment: You keep beating my comments with updates by 2 seconds, thus making my comments irrelevant.  ;)

Comment: @ClayWardell: You can just pass in `self_or_cls` as a first positional argument. `*args` and `**kwargs` do not preclude the use of other positional arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This worked, thanks a lot.  I felt like I tried something like this first but I guess I didn't.  If I wanted to use this on a "naked" function, as opposed to a method, I would just have to include *args, **kwargs in the functions signature, right?

Comment: @ClayWardell: Exactly. Since you cannot really detect when you are decorating a method vs. decorating a function (they are all functions at that moment) you probably have to support two versions still. The work-around is to always only add keyword arguments to your decorator and require that those are called *as keyword parameters*. You then leave `self_or_cls` out altogether.